# How does Java actually store and access variables i.e. memory addresses?

Tags: java

Most tutorials, guides, resources, universities etc. teach us how, when initializing some objects, the actual data gets stored in memory, and the "variable" itself is only a pointer or reference to that block of memory.

So, for the following block of code:

```
Person person = new Person("Name");
```

Let's say the actual data gets stored somewhere randomly in RAM, and the reference to it is `ABC123` - that reference gets assigned to the `person` variable.

So, if we can say that `person` is actually `ABC123` which is the address of the actual data, then what can we say about that address itself? Where and how is `ABC123` (as a value on its own) stored, and when later on using the variable `person`, for example, like so:

```
String name = person.getName();
```

How is the address value `ABC123` looked up?

Is the word "person" parsed as a string? Is there a collection of these references that map to the strings (variable names) - and if so how is that collection itself stored?

Comment: Do you want the answer about how e.g. OpenJDK does it, or do you want the "that's up to the implementation to decide" answer? Generally local variables are stored on the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and each local variable maps to a particular stack offset in the current frame; but in practice a local variable might get mapped to a CPU register, or might not actually exist at runtime at all if the compiler decides to eliminate it.

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134766/where-are-memory-addresses-stored-in-java

Comment: The compiler creates a table/map for variables and their assigned address. In most compiled languages, the variable name is not part of the binary code, only the address.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, this is a question about "how computers work", and in particular, that a location in memory has an identification which we call its "address".

The address does not need to be "stored" in memory (and then you'd be asking about the address of the memory location that held the address).

In your example, the 'person' variable is allocated to one location which has its own address, and that location contains the value 'abc123', which is another address.

There is no 'looking up' to be done, except to the extent that, **during compilation** (not execution), the compiler has structures that hold the properties of names that occur in the source code, and in particular, the corresponding address of names of variables.

(Simplified explanation: at this level is seems pointless to talk about variable scope, stacks, etc.)

Comment: So can you explain that structure that the compiler holds? What is the type of the structure, is it a map, how do variable names as strings point to addresses?

Comment: Variable names are not stored as strings.  Variable names are in fact discarded during compilation.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - thus my bolded words "during compilation". There assuredly is some sort of symbol table maintained by the compiler for the purpose of compiling.

Comment: @eja - you're asking "how does a compiler work"?  Consult any textbook.  The specifics of structure depend on the particular compiler.